# How to use scale() in Interpolations.jl?

Tags: julia, interpolation

I'm interested in the fastest way to linearly interpolate a 1D function on regularly spaced data.
I don't quite understand how to use the `scale` function in `Interpolations.jl`:

```
using Interpolations
v = [x^2 for x in 0:0.1:1]
itp=interpolate(v,BSpline(Linear()),OnGrid())
itp[1]
# 0.0
itp[11]
# 1.0
scale(itp,0:0.1:1)
itp[0]
# -0.010000000000000002
# why is this not equal to 0.0, i.e.  the value at the lowest index?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function does not alter the object, as would be by `scale!`.

```
julia> sitp = scale(itp,0:0.1:1)
11-element Interpolations.ScaledInterpolation{Float64,1,Interpolations.BSplineInterpolation{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1},Interpolations.BSpline{Interpolations.Linear},Interpolations.OnGrid,0},Interpolations.BSpline{Interpolations.Linear},Interpolations.OnGrid,Tuple{FloatRange{Float64}}}:


julia> sitp[0]
0.0
```

thanks to [spencerlyon](https://github.com/tlycken/Interpolations.jl/issues/124#issuecomment-254018927) for pointing that out.